# how to make footer design in bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

How can i design layout of this type. i have designed but some kind of problem occurs when i change resolution of my laptop contents are goes in left side. I am new in bootstrap.    How can i design layout of this type. i have designed but some kind of problem occurs when i change resolution of my laptop contents are goes in left side. I am new in bootstrap.    How can i design layout of this type. i have designed but some kind of problem occurs when i change resolution of my laptop contents are goes in left side. I am new in bootstrap.

This is the footer layout:

[image]

This is bootstrap code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <!--External Css-->
      <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--vertical slide-->


  </head>
<body>


    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                 <div class="row flt">            
            <img src="images/envelope.png">
            <p>San Isidro, Lopez Jaena St.<br>
               Jaro Iloilo City, Philippines 5000<br>       
               Tell: 0927-338-2289<br>
               Email: jennpereira13(at)gmail.com</p>
            <img src="images/envelope.png">
              <p>San Isidro, Lopez Jaena St.<br>
               Jaro Iloilo City, Philippines 5000<br>       
               Tell: 0927-338-2289<br>
               Email: jennpereira13(at)gmail.com</p>
          </div>
        <div class="row flm">
            <h3>Secured Payment Trough:</h3>
            <hr>
            <img src="images/paypal.png" alt="paypal">
            <img src="images/master-card.png" alt="master card">
            <img src="images/google-checkout.png" alt="google-checkout">
            <img src="images/maestro.png" alt="maestro">
            <img src="images/ebay.png" alt="ebay">
            <img src="images/discover.png" alt="discover">
            <img src="images/cirrus.png" alt="cirrus">
            <img src="images/2checkout.png" alt="2checkout">
            <img src="images/visa-electron.png" alt="visa electron">
            <img src="images/direct-debit.png" alt="direct debit">
        </div>
        <div class="row flb">
            <h3>Disclaimer:</h3>
            <hr>
            <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut 
labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in 
voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat 
non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>

            <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut 
labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in 
voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat 
non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
        </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="row footer-right">
                <h1>INCREASE YOUR<br> ENGERGY LEVEL WITH</h1><h1 class="yellow">CUP OF TEA <span>EVERY</span>DAY</h1>
                 <form role="form">
                    <h1><b><img src="images/cup.png">TRY IT TODAY</b></h1>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Your Name">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Your Email">
                  </div>    
                  <button type="submit" class="btn">Order Now</button>
                    <div class="row form-bot">
                        <div class="col-sm-2 lock"><img src="images/lock.png" id="lock"></div> 
                        <div class="col-sm-10 lock-info" ><p>Don’t worry your email infomation is safe with us.<br> We hate spam as much as you hate. </p></div> 
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>


<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What have you tried? please share the relevant HTML/CSS/JS with us so we can guide you in the right direction, as this is what SO is for, not for code writing services

Comment: i want to create layout like given image

Comment: Like said in my initial comment, Please share the relevant HTML/CSS/JS you have made to accomplish this, so we can help you using YOUR code, SO is not a code writing service.

Answer (score 1):

There is no major fault in your layout. But you have targeted the layout only for larger desktop devices **`col-lg-`**, if you need to reflect the changes to iPad and mobile viewport you need to include the bootstrap classes to target those viewports as well.

for example.

```
<div class="col-lg-6"></div> <!--Targets only Large Desktop devices-->
<div class="col-lg-6"></div>
```

If you need to target smaller devices, you need to mention extra bootstrap classes like so,

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-lg-6"></div> <!--Targets both Medium and Large Desktop devices-->
<div class="col-md-9 col-lg-6"></div>
```

This means on Larger desktop devices, the two columns we used will be divided equally into two 6 columns(6 + 6 = 12). But when viewed on medium desktop devices(Desktops 992px and Up), the same two columns are divided into 3 + 9 = 12. Now these values can be obviously changed according to your requirement.

This might help you a lot better.

[image]

Taken from here - https://scotch.io/tutorials/understanding-the-bootstrap-3-grid-system